# If Extra delimiter delete last delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file:

```
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n|||||||||
p|q|r|s|
g|h|i|
w|e|r||
```

Now the 2nd row has an extra delimiter, I want to remove it. How could I do that in unix?

The output should only have 4 pipe delimiter:

```
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r|
```

Comment: use simple `sed` substitution...

Comment: How do I substitute , I think first I need to check  which rows in the files files having extra pipe and have to substitute those line , how to do selective substitution ?

Comment: `'s/\|$//'` should be all you need.

Comment: Sir I have updated the sample input and output file , apologies not mentioning it correctly at first attempt , please let me know how to handle this scenario

Comment: @Kunal your last edit make your question unclear now, How `|` removed from this line `p|q|r|s|` but it doesn't in `g|h|i|`?

Answer (score 2):

I find awk easy to read in such situations:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{NF=4}1' file
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r|
```

Note that this answer doesn't remove trailing pipe symbols, it just sets the columns in the output to be 4. For the following modified example:

```
$ cat file
a|b
x|y|z|n||||
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r||

$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{NF=4}1' file
a|b||
x|y|z|n
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r|
```

Comment: Will it use if I have more than one extra pipe delimiter in the input flle.

Comment: @Kunal no, this sets the number of fields per line. You'll get four columns no matter what. But in your example you only remove trailing pipes if they are in the fifth column...

Comment: @Kunal: I added an example to demonstrate what happens, not sure if it is desirable.

Comment: I think this is perfect , I just need to check by myself , The first row , it has only two pipe in put , have been made 4 in output. Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `grep` one-liner:

```
cat data.csv | grep -Po '^(\w*\|){3}\w*$'
```

You can also do this easily with Python. Here's a Python script that does what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""shortencsv.py"""

import sys

cols = 4

with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        print('|'.join(line.strip().split('|')[:cols]))
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
python shortencsv.py data.csv
```

Comment: I have tried using python , getting an error saying #!/usr/bin/env python2 doesn't exists. I was running my code with following command. ./delimiter_rm.py

Comment: @Kunal Included the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env python2`) so that the solution would be self-documenting as far as the Python version number is concerned. If you run it the way I did (`python shortencsv.py data.csv`) then that line should be ignored. If you run it as an exectuable (`./shortencsv.py data.csv`) then you need to use the correct name for your local `python` interpreter. If you just change `python2` to `python` then that should do it.

Comment: Ok Thank you , Understood , Will give it a try again .

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` to replace one-or-more pipelines at the end of each record with single pipeple.

```
sed 's/|\+$/|/' infile
```

Sample:

```
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n|||
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|sx|sxa
w|e|r||
```

Output:

```
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n|
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|sx|sxa
w|e|r|
```

Comment: The no of pipe per row should be 4 . Not more or not less.

Comment: OK, but your given output doesn't telling this, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/412086/edit) your question and clarify [this my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412086/if-extra-delimiter-delete-last-delimiter/412098#comment738747_412086) as well.

Answer (score 1):

awk is good for more complicated tasks, but this simple task can be done much faster using cut:

```
$ echo "$a"
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n|||||||||
p|q|r|s|
g|h|i|
w|e|r||

$ time awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{NF=4}1' <(for i in {1..100000};do echo "$a";done)

a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r|

real    0m3.850s
user    0m2.105s
sys 0m1.481s

$ time cut -d'|' -f1-4 <(for i in {1..100000};do echo "$a";done)
a|b|c|d
x|y|z|n
p|q|r|s
g|h|i|
w|e|r|
.....
.....

real    0m2.844s
user    0m1.384s
sys 0m1.268s
```

In your case, just use

```
cut -d'|' -f1-4 inputfile
```

Comment: If you notice [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412086/if-extra-delimiter-delete-last-delimiter#comment738760_412094) by OP, he wants to get 4 columns even for input lines that have fewer columns, which `cut` doesn't do.

Comment: But `cut` is indeed much faster than `awk`, your sample considerably downplays the difference, because it includes the `bash` loop in the test. On my pc, with this test `time cat > file <(for i in {1..100000};do echo "$a";done)`, `time awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{NF=4}1' < file >file2`, `time cut -d'|' -f1-4 < file >file2` I got real time `2.346`, `0.816` and `0.102`, so it is about eight times faster. Maybe I'll ask a new question why awk is so slow in this example.

Comment: @user000001 My answer indeed does not comply with the last comment, but on the other hand i can not track any comment in posts... Questions not typed clearly receive corresponding non clear answers. Anyway, i think cut can not comply with the revised expectations.

Comment: @user000001 Your benchmark is the correct one. In my test i just kept the same loop in both awk and cut, and still cut is faster. Maybe because in this case we use a shotgun (awk) to fire a mosquito.